# Why do I get EXE_BAD_INSTRUCTION while using NSCalendar?

Tags: ios, swift, nscalendar

Does anybody know why I would receive the EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION message from the following line:

```
component = NSCalendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: birthDay, to: Date())
```

The purpose is for the user to select a date and the app would then compare the time between the input date and todays date.

Full Code:

```
@IBAction func clickScreenBtn(_ sender: Any) {


    let birthDay = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "birthday") as! Date
    var component = NSCalendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: birthDay, to: Date())


    type = type + 1

    switch type {
    case 0:
        unitLabel.text = "Days"
        timeLabel.text = "\(component.day!)"
        //break



    case 1:
        component = NSCalendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: birthDay, to: Date())
        unitLabel.text = "Hours"
        timeLabel.text = "\(component.hour!)"
        //break
    case 2:
        component = NSCalendar.current.dateComponents([.minute], from: birthDay, to: Date())
        unitLabel.text = "Minutes"
        timeLabel.text = "\(component.minute!)"
        //break
    case 3:
        component = NSCalendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: birthDay, to: Date())
        unitLabel.text = "Seconds"
        timeLabel.text = "\(component.second!)"

    case 4:
        unitLabel.text = "Days"
        timeLabel.text = "\(component.day!)"
        //break

        //break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

I am still new to xCode and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Why are you using `NSCalendar` instead of `Calendar`? [Edit] your question to include enough relevant code to replicate your issue.

Comment: @rmaddy good question. would it be more beneficial for me to use calendar in replace of NSCalendar?

Comment: `Calendar` is the Swift class while `NSCalendar` is the Objective-C class.

Comment: I will take a closer look at that, thanks

Comment: Does it run fine for all the other cases and fail only for `type` as 3? Or does it crash regardless? If the latter, you've probably failed to hook up an outlet.

Comment: It runs fine for ALL case, however if someone enters a date before 1947 OR more than 2086 case 3 crashes the app. I am struggling to find out why.

Comment: I have tried looking at constraints and Wrap/Unwrap but don't seem to find anything. Must be missing something somewhere

Comment: @rmaddy Calendar is a structure not a class. Most of Swift types are structures, just a few are classes like the DateFormatter.

Comment: Note that the two years you mention are both roughly 70 years which are roughly 2^31 seconds away from "now". The duplicate I linked covers the cause of this error.